# RegEx a name with special characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm relative new to RegEx and I've encountered a problem. I want to regex a name. I want it to be max 100 characters, contain at least 2 alphabetic characters and it will allow the character '-'.

I have no problem to only check for alphabetic characters or both alphabetic characters and hyphen but I dont't want a name that potantially can be '---------'.

My code without check for hyphens is

```
var nameRegExp = /^([a-z]){2,100}$/;
```

An explanation for the code is appreciated as well.
Thanks!

Comment: So the string should contain at least one letter, or what exactly is the condition?

Comment: at least 2 letters and it can contain the character '-' but at the same time at least 2 letters

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I missed the 2 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess

```
/^(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])[a-z-]{1,100}$/
```

the lookahead part (`^(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])`) checks if there are at least two letters. This pattern ("start of string, followed by...") is a common way to express additional conditions in regexes.

You can limit the number of `-` by adding a negative assertion, as @Mike [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15865800/989121):

```
/^(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])(?!(?:.*-){11,})[a-z-]{1,100}$/  // max 10 dashes
```

however it might be easier to write an expression that would match "good" strings instead of trying to forbid "bad" ones. For example, this

```
/^[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)*$/
```

looks like a good approximation for a "name". It allows `foo` and `foo-bar-baz`, but not the stuff like `----` or `foo----bar----`.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to add rules to set maximum '-' characters or would it be a lot more complex?

Comment: The last code-snippet is exactly the one I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

To limit the number of `-` you could add a negative look-ahead, where the number `3` is one more than the maximum number you want to allow

```
/^(?!(?:[a-z]*-){3,})(?=-*[a-z]-*[a-z])[a-z-]{2,100}$/
```